# Run-length encoding program

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a string say "AAABBCCCDAAT" so output for the following should be A3B2C3D1A2T1.

```
data = input("enter data ")
count =1
for steps in range(0,len(data)-1):
    if (str(data[steps])==str(data[steps+1])):
        count = count+1
    else:
        str(data[steps])=str(data[steps+1])
        count=1
print ((str(count)+str(data[steps]))
```

i have a string say "AAABBCCCDAAT" so output for the following should be A3B2C3D1A2T1.
Thanks

Comment: I can't post an answer, since the question has been put on hold, but this is called "run-length encoding", and the code here should do the trick: http://pastebin.com/y7fNDtQH.

Comment: Thanks smarx, though i didn't get the code. Any help in getting much simpler code.

Comment: i was using this code, it may have certain bugs.. working on it.          data = input("enter data ")
count =1
for steps in range(0,len(data)-1):
 if (str(data[steps])==str(data[steps+1])):
  count = count+1
 else:
#  str(data[steps])=str(data[steps+1])
  count=1
#print (count)
print ((str(count)+str(data[steps]))

Comment: @user3814582 Maybe post a new question, but use the phrase "run-length encoding" in your question and include your current code. That will make it easier to help.

Comment: @user3814582 Detailed explanation and a different approach (closer to what you were trying) here: http://pastebin.com/cHeaSYZc.

Comment: It seems pretty clear now what the question is.  Reopen?

Comment: I don't know how to get it reopened. i just want to run the code and i couldn't able to solve it.

Comment: @user3814582 As I said, you'll really need to ask a new question. Not enough people will see this to vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
In [62]: from itertools import groupby

In [63]: data
Out[63]: 'AAABBCCCDAAT'

In [64]: ''.join(char + str(len(list(grp))) for char, grp in groupby(data))
Out[64]: 'A3B2C3D1A2T1'
```

Comment: Hey,  could you please explain the code which used groupby I didn't get it clearlly and also could you explain groupby(data) in here, every time I run the code it throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few approaches to share, but I think @Warren Weckesser's answer is better. :-)

```
# Regular expression approach:

import re

def run_length_encode(text):
    # When the match is for AAA:
    # match.group(1) == 'A'
    # match.group(0) == 'AAA'
    # len(match.group(0)) == 3
    def encode_single_run(match):
        return '{}{}'.format(match.group(1), len(match.group(0)))

    # Replace each occurrence of a letter followed by any number of identical letters with the
    # output of encode_single_run on that match
    return re.sub(r'(.)\1*', encode_single_run, text)

assert run_length_encode('AAABBCCCDAAT') == 'A3B2C3D1A2T1'


# While loop approach:

def run_length_encode(text):
    result = []

    position = 0

    # Until we pass the end of the string
    while position < len(text):

        # Grab the current letter
        letter = text[position]
        # Advance our current position
        position += 1
        # Start at a count of 1 (how many times the letter occurred)
        count = 1

        # While we haven't fallen off the array and the letter keeps repeating
        while position < len(text) and text[position] == letter:
            # Move forward
            count += 1
            position += 1

        # Append the letter and count to the result
        result.append((letter, count))

    # At this point, result looks like [('A', 3), ('B', 2), ...]
    # This next line combines the letters and counts and then puts everything into a single string
    return ''.join('{}{}'.format(letter, count) for letter, count in result)

assert run_length_encode('AAABBCCCDAAT') == 'A3B2C3D1A2T1'


# State machine approach:

def run_length_encode(text):
    result = []

    # Keeps track of the letter we're in the midst of a run of
    current_letter = None
    # Keeps track of how many times we've seen that letter
    count = 0

    # Iterate over each letter in the string
    for letter in text:

        # If it's the same letter we're already tracking
        if letter == current_letter:
            count += 1
        else:
            # Unless it's the very start of the process
            if count > 0:
                result.append((current_letter, count))

            # Start tracking the new letter
            current_letter = letter
            count = 1

    # Without this, we'd fail to return the last letter    
    result.append((current_letter, count))

    # At this point, result looks like [('A', 3), ('B', 2), ...]
    # This next line combines the letters and counts and then puts everything into a single string
    return ''.join('{}{}'.format(letter, count) for letter, count in result)

assert run_length_encode('AAABBCCCDAAT') == 'A3B2C3D1A2T1'
```